# VBA # trim string to remove characters

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

i have a file name the i need to remove some characters below is file name and the goal after trim filename.

My Current String = "text_12_12_19.pdl"

New String Goal = "Text.pdl"

Comment: It's a nice goal. Maybe you could show us what you have already trIed?

Comment: You need to describe the rules that determine which characters need to be removed.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to obtain all characters preceding the first underscore, I would suggest the following:

```vb
Function TrimFilename(fnm As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    i = InStr(fnm, "_")
    j = InStrRev(fnm, ".")
    If 0 < i And i < j Then
        TrimFilename = Mid(fnm, 1, i - 1) & Mid(fnm, j)
    Else
        TrimFilename = fnm
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
?TrimFilename("text_12_12_19.pdl")
text.pdl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Split*:

```
MyStringGoal = Split(MyCurrentString, "_")(0) & "." & Split(MyCurrentString, ".")(1)
```

Comment: This is a subscript out of range error if the format doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

'Another solution (can also use left and right) :

```
Dim my_current_string As String
Dim New_String_Goal As String
Dim r As String, l As String

my_current_string = "text_12_12_19.pdl"
l = Left(my_current_string, 4)
r = Right(my_current_string, 4)
New_String_Goal = l & r
Debug.Print New_String_Goal
```